# How to serve a created directory to a user?

Tags: go

How do I serve up a directory that is created server side to a user for them to download it? The directory doesn't just contain files, but sub directories as well.

Comment: do you want to serve the entire directory or specific file?

Comment: @zola the entire directory.

Comment: ive used [gin's static middleware](https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/blob/master/static/static_test.go#L36) but i have never tried updating what is being served at runtime (only useful for making the files available, not downloading as a batch)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Golang specific question or answer but the best solution would be to compress the folder into an archive and have your users download that.